# Ошибка в начале цикла

Tags: python

Ошибка на 4 строке

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\morse.py", line 4, in <module>
    for i in text:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Код:

```
var = str(input('Для зашифровки введите 1, для дешифровки введите 2: '))
if var=='1':
    text=str(input('Введите текст: ')).lower
    for i in text:
        if i =='a':
            endText.append('.-')
        elif i =='б':
            endText.append('-...')
        elif i =='в':
            endText.append('.--')
        elif i =='г':
            endText.append('--.')
        elif i =='д':
            endText.append('-..')
        elif i =='е':
            endText.append('.')
        elif i =='ж':
            endText.append('...-')
        elif i =='з':
            endText.append('--..')
        elif i =='и':
            endText.append('..')
        elif i =='й':
            endText.append('.---')
        elif i =='к':
            endText.append('-.-')
        elif i =='л':
            endText.append('.-..')
        elif i =='м':
            endText.append('--')
        elif i =='н':
            endText.append('-.')
        elif i =='о':
            endText.append('---')
        elif i =='п':
            endText.append('.--.')
        elif i =='р':
            endText.append('.-.')
        elif i =='с':
            endText.append('...')
        elif i =='т':
            endText.append('-')
        elif i =='у':
            endText.append('..-')
        elif i =='ф':
            endText.append('..-.')
        elif i =='х':
            endText.append('....')
        elif i =='ц':
            endText.append('-.-.')
        elif i =='ч':
            endText.append('---.')
        elif i =='ш':
            endText.append('----')
        elif i =='щ':
            endText.append('--.-')
        elif i =='ъ':
            endText.append('.--.-.')
        elif i =='ы':
            endText.append('-.--')
        elif i =='ь':
            endText.append('-..-')
        elif i =='э':
            endText.append('...-...')
        elif i =='ю':
            endText.append('..--')
        elif i =='я':
            endText.append('.-.-')
        elif i =='1':
            endText.append('.----')
        elif i =='2':
            endText.append('..---')
        elif i =='3':
            endText.append('...--')
        elif i =='4':
            endText.append('....-')
        elif i =='5':
            endText.append('.....')
        elif i =='6':
            endText.append('-....')
        elif i =='7':
            endText.append('--...')
        elif i =='8':
            endText.append('---..')
        elif i =='9':
            endText.append('----.')
        elif i =='0':
            endText.append('-----')
        print(endText)
elif var == '2':
    print('asas')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `text` это "указатель на метод". Вы скобки забыли добавить.

```
text=str(input('Введите текст: ')).lower()
```